# Origine e diffusione dell'espressione “dare un colpo di telefono”

Tags: idioms, etymology

Girando per l'Italia ho sentito dire "dagli un colpo di telefono". Sapreste dire se tale espressione è piuttosto comune o meno? O se, diversamente, viene intesa nel suo significato letterale "colpiscilo con il telefono"?

Sarei anche interessato a conoscere l'origine di questa espressione.

Comment: Scusa, ma come potrebbe mai essere intesa letteralmente??

Comment: @martina, potrebbe avvenire se uno, sentita l'espressione, prende il telefono con la mano e colpisce l'altra persona.

Comment: @Kyriakos Kyritsis: credo che la cosa sia veramente ovvia rispetto al contesto. A meno di non star cercando di fare fisicamente del male a qualcuno è chiaro che si tratta di un'espressione figurata. E sicuramente ci sono modi più pratici di fare del male a qualcuno che colpirlo con un telefono...

Comment: @nico Appunto, il mio commento intendeva dire: secondo me non potrebbe mai e in alcuna maniera essere interpretata letteralmente, quindi rimuoverei quella parte nella domanda.

Comment: in fondo si parla di *telefonata*. SDENG!

Comment: In inglese si dice "to ping someone", che non è troppo diverso.

Answer (score 8):

> Sapreste dire se tale espressione è piuttosto comune o meno?

Posso garantire che l'espressione è comune nel Nord Italia, di dove sono originario, e penso anche che sia molto diffusa nel resto del Paese.

> O se, diversamente, viene intesa nel suo significato letterale "colpiscilo con il telefono"?

Decisamente no, in nessun contesto che mi possa venire in mente. Il fatto che la frase sottintenda una comunicazione a distanza, rende ancora meno plausibile un'interpretazione letterale.

Se per qualche buffa coincidenza dovessi colpire qualcuno con un telefono, direi qualcosa del tipo

> L'ho colpito con il telefono.

> Gli ho dato un colpo con il telefono.

(notare l'uso di *con* al posto di *di*)

Circa l'etimologia, ho due ipotesi:

- come già accennava mau nella sua risposta, può essere che ci sia un riferimento ad antiche forme di comunicazione, come dare un *colpo di cannone*, per esempio come avvertimento. Oppure si può pensare alla comunicazione tramite *colpi di tamburo*.
- altrimenti può essere un riferimento al procedimento fisico di effettuare una chiamata con i primi telefoni, in cui era necessario attaccare e risollevare la cornetta per passare tramite il centralino. Tale gesto (data anche la pesantezza dei primi apparecchi telefonici) poteva essere percepita come un *colpo*.

Comment: Secondo me non ci sono connotazioni territoriali, è un'espressione dell'italiano, usata omogeneamente ovunque.

Answer (score 4):

l'espressione è comune, almeno al nord.
Una possibilità è che si sia partiti dall'accezione di *colpo* come «rumore prodotto da un colpo: *sentire i colpi del martello*; detonazione: *colpo del cannone*» (dal De Mauro)

Comment: Common is also *fare un colpo di telefono*

Answer (score 2):

La locuzione "colpo di ..." in italiano è molto comune e non si esaurisce con "colpo di telefono". Ci sono: colpo di fulmine, colpo di scena, colpo di sole, colpo di fortuna, ecc. Si tratta di probabile francesismo; cfr. coup de foudre, un coup de chance, un coup d'état, un coup de Jarnac, ecc.